# Angular 6 subscribe doesn't refresh UI

Tags: angular, typescript

My main problem is that, my component doesn't refresh the UI after I input data. I always use refresh the page to look the changes. I think there is any problem with .subscribe. I use Angular 6. Before that when I use pure And 2 env it works fine.

My component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.company = [];
    this.inputCompanyService.getAllCompany().subscribe(company => {
      this.company = company;
    });
  }


postCompany(event, companyName, ) {
    var result;
    var newCompany = {
      company_name: companyName.value,
      id: companyName.id
    };
    result = this.inputCompanyService.postCompany(newCompany);
    result.subscribe(x => {
      this.company.push(newCompany);
      companyName.value = '';
    });

  }
```

My service:

```
getAllCompany() {
            return this._http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/companys')
                  .map(res => res.json());
      }

postCompany(company_name) {
            var headers = new Headers();
            headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            return this._http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/company', JSON.stringify(company_name), { headers: headers })
                  .map(res => res.json());
      }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="input-company">
  <p>
    <mat-form-field appearance="legacy">
      <input matInput [(ngModel)]="companyName.company_name" placeholder="Here..." autofocus #companyName>
      <!-- <mat-icon matSuffix>sentiment_very_satisfied</mat-icon> -->
    </mat-form-field>
    <button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="postCompany($event, companyName)">Click me !</button>
  </p>
  <div *ngFor="let company of company.company">
    <li>
    <button mat-flat-button (click)="deleteCompany(company)">X</button>
    <button mat-flat-button>N</button>
    <button mat-stroked-button>{{company.id}}-{{company.company_name}}</button>
  </li>    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A nitpick: this line `<div *ngFor="let company of company.company">` looks really bad. You're using three variables/properties with the same name here.

Answer (score 0):

The async call is happening outside of the Angular Zone.

Easiest fix:

```
// Inside the subscribe block to update the variables and force angular to check variables
this._ngZone.run(() => {
    this.company.push(newCompany);
    companyName.value = '';
});
```

You can refactor a little bit if you would like to make use of the AsyncPipe:

```
this.companies$: Observable<any>;
ngOnInit() {
    this.companies$ = this.inputCompanyService.getAllCompany();
}
```

and the template...

```
<div class="input-company">
  <p>
    <mat-form-field appearance="legacy">
      <input matInput [(ngModel)]="companyName.company_name" placeholder="Here..." autofocus #companyName>
      <!-- <mat-icon matSuffix>sentiment_very_satisfied</mat-icon> -->
    </mat-form-field>
    <button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="postCompany($event, companyName)">Click me !</button>
  </p>
  <ng-container *ngIf="(companies$ | async) as companies)"
    <div *ngFor="let company of companies.company">
      <li>
       <button mat-flat-button (click)="deleteCompany(company)">X</button>
       <button mat-flat-button>N</button>
       <button mat-stroked-button>{{company.id}}-{{company.company_name}}</button>
     </li>    
    </div>
  <ng-container>
</div>
```

Good luck!

Comment: Async call is most certainly *not* happening outside of the Zone.

Answer (score 0):

You're retrieving companies and storing them in an array..

```
this.company = [];
this.inputCompanyService.getAllCompany().subscribe(company => {
      this.company = company;
});
```

However, you're iterating through `company.company` in the template:

```
<div *ngFor="let company of company.company">
```

It should be:

```
 <div *ngFor="let c of company">
   <li>
    <button mat-flat-button (click)="deleteCompany(c)">X</button>
    <button mat-flat-button>N</button>
    <button mat-stroked-button>{{c.id}}-{{c.company_name}}</button>
  </li>    
 </div>
```

I renamed variable to `c` to avoid confusion. You should also consider renaming the array to `companies` so that it is easier to understand.